# Backup an installed software

Tags: installation, backup, windows-registry

I have some important installed software applications, and I want to backup such applications only (not all disk). Is there any software that can backup those applications (including registry?)

Answer (score 2):

No, not really. Windows does not store what registry keys a program uses so there is no real way for a 3rd party backup program to know what to save from the registry. The same goes for shared files like DLL's that may not be installed in your program's install directory.

One option is use a tool like [sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) and install the program inside the sandbox. You then can look at the sandbox and see what files the program wrote out to. However this does not help you detect if the program needed a shared DLL, saw it existed, then did nothing. If you restore your "Backup" the DLL may not be there on the new system and the program may not work.

Comment: What about an `Export Settings..` user command? That get's the job done, but it's not always available.

Comment: @zero2cx What `Export Settings` are you referring to? If the program has a "Export settings" feature that is great, but that is not a program to "backup such applications only (not all disk)" if you are referring to the [Windows Easy Transfer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer) it is not guaranteed to get all of the settings (as per the FAQ)

Comment: "If the program has a "Export settings" feature that is great". Yes, that is all I meant. That is great, because it can allow you to 1) export 2) uninstall 3) install wherever 4) import.